# How do I get rid of adsense.previewmediastation.com hijacking?

Tags: malware

When I do a google search in IE8 all links are redirected to adsense.previewmediastation.com.

My antivirus software (Norton) is not picking anything up. How do I get rid of this?

Comment: Does it happen in IE safe mode or in Chrome?

Comment: Not chrome. What is ie safe mode?

Comment: In the Start Menu, under accessories.

Comment: Take a look at http://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a BHO (Browser Helper Object) that is being evil.
Go to Tools, Manage Addons in IE and disable everything.

Also, look for suspicious entries in [shexview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) and autoruns.

Comment: Then use HijackThis to examine them and remove any from companies you don't recognize, or that are blank.